# Howto add a file with addFileAttachmentAsync from OneDrive for Business

Tags: outlook-addin, office-js, outlook-web-addins

I want to use the Office.js / Outlook method addFileAttachmentAsync to add a file from OneDrive to a new composed mail message. This file is shared with me by another Office365 user. If I use the Onedrive interface to create a link and add the text '&download=1' it all works like a charm.

If I use Graph createLink to create a link we do get an URI and that URI seems to work but generates an error as soon as the upload is done.

How can I generate a URI with Graph that works?

Thanks in advance for your effort!

Wilco

The handmade URI looks like this:

https://softmakersbv-my.sharepoint.com/:i:/g/personal/tim_softmakers_nl/EWu4nf4kBMBKv4xrfGe91JABLpUSye9VgVJgxhlapA2eiQ?e=1KWtPD

and the Graph generated URI looks like this:

https://softmakersbv-my.sharepoint.com/personal/tim_softmakers_nl/Documents/TimDocuments-00003/2019/04/19.04.00188.png

---

Even if we make sure that the link is publically accessable we cannot use it for addFileAttachmentAsync. Using Graph Createlink with the following command:

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/01ATENY5KYPNW2NH64F5CJEWPK4DYIHSX7/createLink

with the following body  {"type": "edit", "scope": "anonymous"} delivers the webUrl:

https://softmakersbv-my.sharepoint.com/:i:/g/personal/tim_softmakers_nl/EVh7baaf3C9Eklnq4PCDyv8BbjtwqSi-a92qYg0EYEE0kA

If I use the OneDrive interface to create the same link the result is as follows:

https://softmakersbv-my.sharepoint.com/:i:/g/personal/tim_softmakers_nl/EVh7baaf3C9Eklnq4PCDyv8BbjtwqSi-a92qYg0EYEE0kA?e=fCWoUK

The second URL works. The only difference is the last part ?e=fCWoUK. How can I get the needed last part from Graph?

---

Images of results

Result of small url (returned by graph): https://softmakersbv-my.sharepoint.com/:i:/g/personal/wilcotroost_softmakers_nl/EaNXPGdDsBBDo_uVZPK2c0EB6gHaA3ASNj5ly0QyzKGgzQ?e=G30d5L

Result of longer url (handmade): https://softmakersbv-my.sharepoint.com/:i:/g/personal/wilcotroost_softmakers_nl/EUuTYN05rlNNpYn0IG7FMfkBnnCu6yUUdbj72YcsTc5Wow?e=jWU5Mw

Requested code example

```
          let _fileName = 'Picos de Europa'

          // graph url ..v1.0/me/drive/items/01ATENY5KYPNW2NH64F5CJEWPK4DYIHSX7/createLink  {"type": "edit", "scope": "anonymous"}
          //let _fileUrl = 'https://softmakersbv-my.sharepoint.com/:i:/g/personal/tim_softmakers_nl/EVh7baaf3C9Eklnq4PCDyv8BbjtwqSi-a92qYg0EYEE0kA' 

          // handmade url (create link from the onedrive interface)
          let _fileUrl = 'https://softmakersbv-my.sharepoint.com/:i:/g/personal/tim_softmakers_nl/EVh7baaf3C9Eklnq4PCDyv8BbjtwqSi-a92qYg0EYEE0kA?e=fCWoUK'            

          Office.context.mailbox.item.addFileAttachmentAsync(_fileUrl + '&download=1', _fileName, {}, (result) => {
            console.log(result)
          })
```

Only the handmade link Url works. My problem is that I like to create a link with the Graph API.

Comment: Can you help me with which graph API you used ?

Comment: Do you mean if last part(?e=fCWoUK) is missing you are not able to attach file using addFileAttachmentAsync API? I tried with both the urls shared by you and was able to attach both files as they are publicly accessible. can you please share what error you are getting when you are using url without last part **?e=fCWoUK** ?

Comment: Thanks again for your time! There is no error message. The response of [addFileAttachmentAsync] is OSF.DDA.AsyncResult {value: "b5db42d1-a33c-4b2a-9eb8-96f406feeea915556209423260", status: "succeeded"} If I use the url without the last part only a small part of the file gets loaded. You can see the difference in the images in the original message.

Comment: Can you help me with following:Are you seeing this issue in outlook web application or desktop clients (windows or mac) or mobile ? Also can you please share the screenshot of the instance where you say small part of file gets loaded.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT We are using the outlook web application and you can find the screenshot of the partly loaded file in the url I added to the original message last time. ( https://softmakersbv-my.sharepoint.com/:i:/g/personal/wilcotroost_softmakers_nl/EaNXPGdDsBBDo_uVZPK2c0EB6gHaA3ASNj5ly0QyzKGgzQ?e=G30d5L )

Comment: 1. We looked at the screenshot you have shared but we couldn't figure out what do you mean by attachment is partially attached? Do you mean that file is attached but after download it does not open in your image viewer application?
2. When you say that "The second URL works.": Are you able to attach the attachment using the URL successfully, download it and view it in image viewer application correctly?

Comment: Also, 3. What we observe here is that the URL which you have shared with us is html page and you are trying to attach the HTML page as (probably) png filename. HTML page gets attached successfully but if you try to download such attachment and view it in your ImageViewer application, it will throw error as file is not a png.
So, Please make sure you use URL which points directly to image resource. Example: https://softmakersbv-my.sharepoint.com/personal/tim_softmakers_nl/Documents/TimDocuments-00003/2019/04/19.04.00188.jpg in your API.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT Please read the original message; The first 4 links are examples of the source of the file to be atached. The last 2 links are just screenshots showing you the difference of the results. If you take a look at the bytesize difference between the 2 screenshots you conclude with us that it is partially loaded.

Comment: Can you please share the code snippet where you are using addFileAttachmentAsync API

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT I added the code example to the original message

Comment: In addFileAttachmentAsync, you should be using URL of image/file (resource) which you need to attach. In your code, you are providing URL of HTML page which is showing you the image. For example: For this URL: https://softmakersbv-my.sharepoint.com/:i:/g/personal/tim_softmakers_nl/EWu4nf4kBMBKv4xrfGe91JABLpUSye9VgVJgxhlapA2eiQ?e=1KWtPD , you should be using https://softmakersbv-my.sharepoint.com/personal/tim_softmakers_nl/Documents/TimDocuments-00003/2019/04/19.04.00188.png in the API.

Comment: Note that with URL: https://softmakersbv-my.sharepoint.com/:i:/g/personal/tim_softmakers_nl/EWu4nf4kBMBKv4xrfGe91JABLpUSye9VgVJgxhlapA2eiQ?e=1KWtPD&download=1 , it is also a webpage (HTML) which has image embeded in it.

Comment: This URL: https://softmakersbv-my.sharepoint.com/personal/tim_softmakers_nl/Documents/TimDocuments-00003/2019/04/19.04.00188.png will also not work in API - because this is not "truely" publicly accessible. If you open any browser in cognito (private) mode and hit this URL, you will be asked to login - which proves that this is not publicly available URL - requirement for addFileAttachmentAsync API.

Comment: Ok @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT I would love to provide an url that fulfills all requirements. The big question is: How do I create such an Url with the Graph API. Using [sendLink] I only get the ones above. What Graph API call(s) should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution for this problem proofed to be more simple then anticipated. It was clear that the URL's given by the Graph API did not cut the cake. The Outlook Add-Ins team was clear on this. The big and remaining question was; how do I get a correct URL from Graph.

The correct answer is; you do not need a function like createLink! If you just use the ID of a OneDrive file item to get the properties (like https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0//me/drive/items/01ATEIIBJLT455YK5FLISCBD37Y7SWE) you will find a property @microsoft.graph.downloadUrl that holds the correct URL. This URL is valid for the timespan of an hour and can be used succesfull with addFileAttachmentAsync in Office.js

Thanks for the time you people invested in my question.

Wilco.

Answer (score 2):

The URI that you want to use for the `addFileAttachmentAsync` API should be publicly accessible.

To test, if you open a fresh private browser or incognito mode, you should be able to access the URI without logging in.

In this case, the first URI (with &download=1 appended) is publicly accessible where as the second one is not.

Please check your graph API to generate a URI that is publicly accessible.

Comment: Thanks for your input! I am afraid it's not a fix for me. The rest of my response is in the original message

Comment: Please check original message for reply